# How to get the reduced chi-squared value for a best fit line/curve with error bars on both x and y axis?

Tags: fitting

Suppose I have a set of data ({xi,yi},like data from lab experiment) and I have errors associated with each xi and yi. If I do a best-fit line/curve, how do I get the reduced chi-squared value for that line/curve in Mathematica?

Comment: You've assumed a fair amount of statistical knowledge (although I'm a bit skeptical that one can do a "best-fit line/curve" procedure followed by a "reduced chi-squared value"  - also called an overdispersion parameter - and have everything adjusted properly when there are errors in both variables).  I think a reference to the procedure and an attempt at some *Mathematica* code is in order.  Alternatively, you might want to ask this question at the CrossValidated site.